# Change input field value depending on what a link has

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a link that is always changing and I want it to print some text into an input text field depending on where the link points to. For example my link could look like the following.

```
<a onclick="main()" id="link" href="#foo">
```

or the same link at times could look like

```
<a id="link" href="#bar">
```

If the link links to to #foo then I want the following to look like

```
<input id="input" type="text" value="Hello World" />
```

And if the link links to #bar then I need the input to have a value of Good Bye World.

How can acheave this. I tried the following but I think it doesn't work because URL doesn't change until the user clicks on it. SO it is looking for something that isn't there yet.

```
function main() {
  var url = window.location.href;
  if (url.search("#foo") > 0) {
    document.getElementById("link").value = "#foo";
    document.getElementById("input").value = "Hello World";
  }
}
```

**UPDATE** Here's a list of some of the hash tags the one link could be. And what the input text field would say when the links are clicked.

```
#work = Can't talk I'm at work
#home = I have kids I still can't talk
#bar = I'm busy getting drunk I can't talk
#bathroom = Listen you perv I'm not interested don't you get it.
```

But remember the site is originally located at example.com has the link that can have any of the above hash tags it links to. And when user clicks that one link depending on what the links href has as a hash tag determines what will be entered in the input field.

Comment: It looks like your `<input>` does not have the _id_ `input` which you're trying to use in your code to look it up.

Comment: It's just an example. I know I would need to put id's on those.

Answer (score 1):

This should work, but you can't test it with jsfiddle.  Hopefully this helps you understand.

JS:

```
document.getElementById('link').onclick = function () {
    var url = window.location.href;
    if (url.indexOf("#foo") > -1) {
        document.getElementById("link").innerHTML = "#foo";
        document.getElementById("input").value = "Hello World";
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<a id="link" href="#foo">link</a>
<input id="input">
```

Comment: Nope because http://jsfiddle.net/BF7fF It needs to happen when the user clicks on the link which is why think it isn't working

Comment: oops i forgot about that. I was mainly talking about the jsfiddle run frame trying to access the outer frame's url

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to check the hash part of the current URL, if so that would be the `location.hash`, if you're trying to check the actual attribute of the clicked link, you should probably use `getAttribute` instead ?

```
function main() {
    var hash = window.location.hash,
        inp  = document.getElementById("input");

    if (hash == '#foo') {
        inp.value = "Hello World";
    }else if (hash == '#bar') {
        inp.value = "Goodbye World";
    }else{
        inp.value = "Stick a fork in me";
    }
}
```

You would of course have to close those anchors and have valid markup !

**EDIT:**

You could get rid of the inline onclick and just do:

```
$(window).on('hashchange', main);
```

Comment: When the link gets clicked then the input box gets updated. So the user could be on example.com and clicks on the link for example.com/#foo when he does that then the input box gets updated

Comment: @BenP.Dorsi-Todaro - It really sounds like what you need is to get rid of the inline js and attach event handler to the hashchange event instead.

Comment: The [hashchange event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/hashchange) triggers everytime the hash changes, and that's what you'd normally bind to, as that would make sure the hash has actually changed when the function is called.

Comment: And that would work. The link is created from keywords that the user types in. So depending on what word is typed determines what the link will be

Comment: As long as the hash changes, the hashchange event will fire.

Comment: I see this is on mozilla will this work for non mozilla browsers. I'm also not understanding. Lets say the link is static the entire time the user is on the site but when he goes back again it is different or if he refreshes it changes but as long as the user is there and hasn't refreshed the link will stay the same will it still work?

Comment: A link that only changes the hash, like `<a href="#foo"></a>` does not reload the page, instead it fires the hashchange event. MDN is the Mozilla Foundation's pages for coding stuff, and the code listed there will work everywhere or specific browsers will be listed. The hashchange event works everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

make the id of the text input to "hello" and do the following

```
function main(){
    if(url.indexOf("foo") != -1){
        document.getElementById("hello").value = "Hello World foo";   
    }else{
        document.getElementById("hello").value = "Hello World bar";  
    }
}

 <input type="text" id="hello" value="Hello World" />
```